# I receive a unsupported media type error when doing a rest request using oauth

Tags: rest, delphi, oauth-2.0, indy

I'm using delphi 11.3 to make a rest request using oauth2.
I get the token, then I need to call again another api to send my json and the token.
I'm receiving "unsupported media type"
can I have some help?
this is the code used for testing:

```
var slJSON: TStringList;
begin
  slJSON := TStringList.Create;
  slJSON.LoadFromFile('c:\temp\json.txt');

  // Get TOKEN
  OAuth2Authenticator1.ClientID     := 'xxx';
  OAuth2Authenticator1.ClientSecret := 'yyy';
  OAuth2Authenticator1.Scope := 'zzz';
  OAuth2Authenticator1.AccessTokenEndpoint := 'mylink';
  OAuth2Authenticator1.AuthorizeWithClientCredentials;

  RESTRequest1.Method  := rmPOST;
  RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'mylink2';
  RESTRequest1.Resource := 'myfunction';

  // BOOKING
  with RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem do
   begin
     Name  := 'test';
     Value := slJSON.Text;
     ContentType := TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_JSON;
     Kind := TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkREQUESTBODY;
   end;

  with RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem do
    begin
      Options := [];
      Options := Options + [TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode];
      Name := 'Authorization';
      Value := 'Bearer ' + OAuth2Authenticator1.AccessToken;
      Kind := TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER;
      ContentType := TRESTContentType.ctTEXT_PLAIN;
    end;

  RESTRequest1.Execute;

  slJSON.Free;
end;
```

Can I have some help?
Thank you

Comment: Because you're sending a HTTP POST with the content type `multipart/*` since you want different (sub) content types in every parameter. Most common example is [`multipart/form-data`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28380690/4299358) to upload files. Inspect your actual HTTP traffic with f.e. [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) and you should notice it differs drastically from what you think you send - the server is correct in telling you he doesn't expect/want the way you send it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem myself:

1. I had to move the authorization param before the other param
2. I had to change the kind of the json.

Like this it works:

```
var slJSON: TStringList;
begin
  slJSON := TStringList.Create;
  slJSON.LoadFromFile('c:\temp\json.txt');

  // Get TOKEN
  OAuth2Authenticator1.ClientID     := 'xxx';
  OAuth2Authenticator1.ClientSecret := 'yyy';
  OAuth2Authenticator1.Scope := 'zzz';
  OAuth2Authenticator1.AccessTokenEndpoint := 'mylink';
  OAuth2Authenticator1.AuthorizeWithClientCredentials;

  RESTRequest1.Method  := rmPOST;
  RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'mylink2';
  RESTRequest1.Resource := 'myfunction';

  // BOOKING
  with RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem do
    begin
      Options := [];
      Options := Options + [TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode];
      Name := 'Authorization';
      Value := 'Bearer ' + OAuth2Authenticator1.AccessToken;
      Kind := TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER;
      ContentType := TRESTContentType.ctTEXT_PLAIN;
    end;

  with RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem do
   begin
     Name  := 'test';
     Value := slJSON.Text;
     ContentType := TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_JSON;
     Kind := TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST;
   end;
```

Comment: it seems I cannot add the <code> tag correctly in the answer, I don't know why

Comment: Looks better now. I only modified the part above and below the code.

Comment: Ok thank you. If anybody could help me understand why changing the kind to pkGETorPOST made it work I would be greatful.